# Using CustomView as a rootview in fragment

Tags: android, layout, fragment

**In Activity's** onCreate Method we can do the following

```
     QuickReturnHeaderHelper helper = new QuickReturnHeaderHelper(this,
                R.layout.activity_product_detail,R.layout.product_details_footer);
     wholeView = helper.createView(productDetailDTO.isOwner());
     setContentView(wholeView);
```

**In fragment**,we can return a layout from onCreateView(), we can inflate it from a layout resource defined in XML. To help us do so, onCreateView() provides a LayoutInflater object.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Now, I want to use

> whole view i.e my custom view

as my fragments rootview.I dont want to inflate if from a layout resource defined in XML.
 But, until now I have not been able to do so. I have been searching in google for past few days but searching didnot produce any result. So, here I am posting this question.

Comment: What's your requirements exactly, didn't get you Prativa

Comment: instead of inflating a view through layout resource I want to be able to use a custom view in android just as we can do it in Activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535454/custom-view-with-xml-layout-in-android chk ths if it should b helpful to u

Comment: found useful or not prativa?

Comment: done o not this prativa??

Answer (score 0):

I do not get your question completely but in my opinion what you can do is create an empty xml file(with relative layout only) and inflate it then add your custom view to it. Hope this will work, sorry if i was wrong